# Newbie: how to remove tangled vertices?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, transforms, sculpting

[image: donut]

Been racking my brain and google trying to figure out how to delete the vertices highlighted without putting a hole in it or messing up the mesh. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: it's hard to understand how your topology looks like but if you delete maybe Grid Fill will help to rebuild?

Comment: I tried something like that but I'm not too sure how grid fill works. I select two opposite points and grid fill and nothing really happens even after I adjust the offset and split.

Comment: maybe share this part of your object? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/d273faedf7fd463e859c6707527c29e2

Comment: Your mesh is a bit messy here, you have inner vertices for example. More generally, don't apply the Subdivision Surface modifier if you don't need to

Comment: got it. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it a bit. Dissolved the tangled vertices and manually selected the lines and filled the grid.